# Proving that a set relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I'm solving an exercise about equivalence relations. I have to show that this relation is an equivalent relation:

> We define in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ the relation given by $(x,y)R(a,b)\iff
> > \exists n\in \mathbb{Z}(n-1<y\leq n   \wedge n-1<b\leq n)$

To show that it is an equivalent relation I have to prove that it is Reflexive, Symmetric and Transitive. I don't know how to prove that it is transitive.

For reflection: $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}(n-1<y\leq n   \wedge n-1<y\leq n)$ is always true.

For symmetry: $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}(n-1<y\leq n   \wedge n-1<b\leq n) \iff \exists n\in \mathbb{Z}(n-1<b\leq n   \wedge n-1<y\leq n)$ is always true because the and operator is conmutative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried writing down a few concrete examples of related pairs?

Comment: Yes! I know that for every real y, the n has to be unique: if y is an integer then n=y and if it's not, then n=[y]+1. But I don't know how to write that properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The relation  is of the form $\alpha R\beta\iff f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$.
Here $f\colon \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb Z$, $(x,y)\mapsto \lceil y\rceil$

Comment: I don't understand what can I do with this! :(

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have $(x,y)R(a,b)$ and $(a,b)R(e,f)$.  Then you have

$\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}(n-1<y\leq n   \wedge n-1<b\leq n)$

and

$\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(m-1<b\leq m   \wedge m-1<f\leq m)$

In particular you have 
$∃n∈Z(n−1<b≤n)$ and $∃m∈Z(m−1<b≤m)$.  Try to show that you must have $m$ = $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $a\sim b\iff f(a)=f(b)$ then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

Now see the hint of **Hagen**.

If it comes to e.g. symmetry then is simply enough to observe that:$$f(a)=f(b)\implies f(b)=f(a)$$

Proving that the relation is reflexive and transitive is of the same level.